# 90s (or late 80s?) TV show about fashion and Carnaby street

Tags: story-identification, tv

Does anyone have any details on a British TV show from the nineties about a rock band that featured the idea that fashion was a living entity under Carnaby Street? The only other detail I remember was that fashion starts to go wrong and it ends up with a banana turning straight.

Comment: The Glam Metal Detectives was on BBC in the mid 90s, so within the time frame. Sounds like a plot-line from one of the segments.

Comment: I remember The Glam Metal Detectives and it's not that, thank you though.